# Return type of node itself in xpath

Tags: java, xpath, cfml

Having the following xml

```
<xml>
 <property href="abc">b</property>
 <element attr="def">k</element>
</xml>
```

How can I make the following xpath return literally `element`.

```
*[@attr='def']
```

On it's own this might seem a weird thing to do, but using the above xpath I can't find the node type itself (only the attributes and children).

Comment: You tagged this as `java`; does that mean that you're getting a `Node` or `NodeList` and need to process it? Or are you looking to get a string value for something like XSLT?

Comment: Can you clarify for us whether you want the name of the xml element (e.g., `property` or `element` in your sample xml) or the **xml node type** (e.g., element, attribute, text, etc). You know that `*` in XPath *always* means "xml element", right?

Comment: Sorry btw for the slow reaction, wrote this at work and tend to check once I get home, but yesterday I fell asleep straight away O:).

Either way, I meant what Martin Honnen's answer gave me and I think I need to brush up my xml/xpath terminology knowledge... :S .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the name of an element node then use `name(*[@attr = 'def'])` or `local-name(*[@attr = 'def'])`.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked: "How can I make the following xpath return **literally element**" (emphasis added).

Comment: How is this answer not what the OP asked?

Comment: @FrancisAvila - if the quote that I already referenced is not enough, how about the question's title? The *name* of a node is not its *type*.

Comment: Given the OP's sample xml and sample XPath (which always returns an element node, by definition), I think the OP is not using "type" to mean "node type", but something application-defined (e.g., "type: property" or "type: element").

Comment: I might not be sure about xpath terminology, but the type of `<element>` seems to me to be `element`, so `name(*[@attr = 'def'])` gave me exactly what I needed. Thanks so very very much Martin, this really saved me a lot of trouble (would have had to restructure the format of all the relevant xml documents otherwise).